# Managed Metadata fields' settings are not the same as in content type hub after publishing

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub

I have created a content type hub with some columns and content types and then I published them using powershell. Using powershell, I subscribed to the content type hub. The strange thing is that the settings of the fields in the other site are not the same as I have set them up in the content type hub.

What could be the reason?

I have republished the content types and resubscribed but it still the same.